# How to read a whole file in Python? To work universally in command line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to read  a whole file in Python? I would like my script to work however it is called

- `script.py log.txt`
- `script.py < log2.txt`
- `python script.py < log2.txt`
- `python -i script.py logs/yesterday.txt`

You get the idea.

---

I tried

```
import fileinput
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = fileinput.input()
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
```

But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visual-studio-extension-load-times.py", line 5, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: like `f = open(fileinput.input())` but with correct exception handling and stuff?

Comment: Do you want to read from stdin rather than reading the arguments and then open and read file?

Comment: answers below deal with reading in filenames as command line arguments but if you also want it robust to flags like -i check out [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)

Comment: The `-i` flag in the fourth example is to Python, not my script. My script doesn't take any flags, it's pretty dumb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `fileinput`, open the file directly yourself:

```
import sys
try:
    fileobj = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
except IndexError:
    fileobj = sys.stdin

with fileobj:
    data = fileobj.read()
```

Comment: @mgilson: Coz this is simple enough?

Comment: @mgilson: `python -i` switches to interactive mode, but `sys.argv` is still the same as the other variants.

Comment: Oh right.  Sorry.  Apparently reading too much today has dulled my brain.  sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

further more, to open a file passed from the command line you can do:
(also, this is a smarter way to open files, instead of `f = open(...)` you can do `with ...`)

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

The reason for `with` being a smarter way to open files, is because it will automaticlly close the file after you leave the indented `with` block.
This means you don't have to "worry" about files being open or forgotten for to long (that can cause "to many open filehandles" from your OS)

---

Then to `sys.argv`

`sys.argv[1]` will be the first parameter on the command line after your python file.
`sys.argv[0]` will be your scripts name. for instance:

`python myscript.py heeyooo` will be:

- `sys.argv[0] == "myscript.py"`
- `sys.argv[1] == "heeyooo"` :)

Then there's all sorts of modules that will be interesting to you when working with files.
For one, `os.path` is a good start because you will most likely want to do as much cross-platform as possible and this gives you the option to convert `\` into `/` on Linux and vice versa.
A few good ones are:

- os.path.abspath
- os.path.isfile
- os.path.isdir

You also have `os.getcwd()` which might be good :)

Answer (score 3):

argparse to the rescue!:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
...                     default=sys.stdin)
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>> file_data = args.infile.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
script.py log.txt
script.py < log2.txt
```

These two are *very* different invocations of your script! In the first, the shell passes the filename `log.txt` to the script; in the second, the shell connects the script's standard input to the file `log2.txt`, and the script never actually sees the filename.

It *is* possible to handle both of these in the same script. One way to do it is to read from standard input if no files are passed on the command line. Another way is to read from standard input if it's not a terminal and then *also* read files listed on the command line, if any (I do like `fileinput` for this if you are interested in reading the lines but don't care what file they come from). You can use `sys.stdin.isatty()` which returns `True` if the standard input is a terminal. So something like this:

```
import sys, fileinput
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    for line in sys.stdin:
         process(line)
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

But if you are looking to process each file as a whole, as it appears, then `fileinput` won't do. Instead, read each filename from the command line individually, read the indicated file, and process it:

```
import sys
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    stdin = sys.stdin.read()
    if stdin:
        process(stdin)
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        process(f.read())
```

Now with regard to these invocations:

```
python script.py < log2.txt
python -i script.py logs/yesterday.txt
```

These are the same as though you had just invoked `script.py` directly as far as the script can tell, so you don't need to handle them specially. Using the `-i` option *with* input indirection (`<`) could cause some unexpected behavior, but I haven't tried it (and there wouldn't be any way to work around it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you really wanted `fileinput` in the first place, since you're not trying to concatenate multiple files, handle the name `-` as "put stdin here", etc.

But if you *do* want `fileinput`, instead of trying to reproduce all of its behavior, just wrap it up.

You want to read all of the input into one string, but all it provides is functions that give you one line or one file at a time. So, what can you do? Join them together:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(fileinput.input()))
```

That's it.

Comment: I tried `''.join(f)` it printed an infinite amount of weird text. Maybe a unicode problem?

Comment: What does "it printed an infinite amount of weird text" mean? There's no way just calling `join` could cause _anything_ to get printed. Without knowing your actual code, and the data you ran it on, and the expected and actual output, it's very hard to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Went with this.

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open(sys.argv[1] ) if sys.argv[1:] else sys.stdin
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
```